# How do i cascade delete or update specific in one to many relation in typeorm?

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

i have two tables, invoice and product, it is one to many relation,

i have declared cascade in relationship, so when i insert data of invoice with product using typeorm, it automatically make entry in product table, which is expected behaviour in create,

But in edit,

Let’s say the original entry was original:{i:1, ps:[{p:1},{p:2}]}

The new entry is
edit:{i:1,ps:[{p:1}]}

So the original invoice had 2 products but in the new edit, the user has removed one of the products from invoice.

what currently happing is it is just removing from relation(setting refrence key to null in product table), but not deleting the product.

i are going to use product table for indexing and analytics so this on edit function needs to be properly, is there any other way other than manually deleting those products and recreating , can't i just updat existing ones ?

Anything available in typeorm?

Using save on type orm gives the above unexpected behaviour.

I tried update in typeorm, but it’s a known issue open on the library since 2 years without any update.

What other ways can I achieve the above?